# How to setup testing environment for smart contract in solidity

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am following https://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/solidity-tests to set up a test in solidity for smart contract. Here is my `test.sol`

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Auction.sol";

const Auction_sol = artifacts.require("./Auction.sol");

contract TestAuction {

}
```

But I am constantly have the error below about missing `artifacts`:

```
Error: Could not find artifacts for ./test.sol from any sources
    at Resolver.require (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\.-resolver\index.js:37:1)
    at TestResolver.require (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\.-core\lib\testing\testresolver.js:17:1)
    at C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\.-core\lib\test.js:109:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\.-core\lib\test.js:107:1
```

What I am missing here? It seems to be simple task but somehow the online post did not work for me.

Here is the 2_deploy_contracts.js

```
var Auction = artifacts.require("Auction");
const Auction_sol = artifacts.require('Auction.sol');  //this line seems no use

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Auction);
},
```

Here is the portion of smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract Auction {

    // Data
    //Structure to hold details of the item
    struct Item {
        uint itemId; // id of the item
        uint[] itemTokens;  //tokens bid in favor of the item

    }

   //Structure to hold the details of a persons
    struct Person {
        uint remainingTokens; // tokens remaining with bidder
        uint personId; // it serves as tokenId as well
        address addr;//address of the bidder
    }

    mapping(address => Person) tokenDetails; //address to person
    Person [4] bidders;//Array containing 4 person objects

    Item [3] public items;//Array containing 3 item objects
    address[3] public winners;//Array for address of winners
    address public beneficiary;//owner of the smart contract

    uint bidderCount=0;//counter

    //functions

    function Auction() public payable{    //constructor
  ......................
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're new to Truffle, I encourage you to start with [Ethereum pet shop -- your first dapp](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop).

Your code should something like:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Auction.sol";


contract TestAuction {

 Auction auction = Auction(DeployedAddresses.Auction());

}
```

**Edit:**

Error is because name of your test contract file and actual contract name are different. Your contract filename and contract name should be equal.

Rename contract file from `test.sol` to `TestAuction.sol` and run it.

Comment: Tried and the error is the same. I did js version of test successfully and want to do the same with solidity.

Comment: It would be more better if you can share your full code somewhere, I have tried to reproduce the issue with meta-coin truffle, but seems working fine

Comment: Added `Auction.sol` and `2_deploy_contracts.js` to the post. Let me know if you want to see more file. Thanks.

Comment: @user938363, answer updated, please give a try with appropriate changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `const Auction_sol = artifacts.require("Auction");`

Comment: The error is the same.

Comment: That is not a valid solidity code outside a `contract`.